# Unable to write file with nano, but vim works, how can I debug this?

Tags: linux

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 Server LTS

So, even as the root user, trying to save a file with nano just gives me the visual bell, no error about permissions, no nothing. This started out of the blue and problem persists even after rebooting.

I just tested vim, and I can write files with it without issue.

Comment: The OS is in the first line of my post, Ubuntu 14.04. Cli input? Bash if I understood your question right. I've checked syslog, but not .nanorc, thanks for the tip. I open files with `nano filename`, and I also tried it as root as well as via sudo.

Comment: There was no .nanorc in /var/log or /home/user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was Open SSH Client for Windows 10 (beta). The keycodes it was sending were fucky. Entering into `bash` from `cmd` before SSH-ing into the Ubuntu box sorted the problem.